# Fingerprint API Android

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

Hi I'm new to android development. I'd like to practice this Fingerprint API in M (6.0 Marshmallow) and N (7.0 Nougat). But this sample [Github Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AsymmetricFingerprintDialog) seems only for verify the current user when the fingerprint is set on `Settings > Security > Fingerprint`.

Is there any tutorial on how the fingerprint is save from the android phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my experience with it, you can't use native fingerprint sensor introduced in Android M as user attendance system, So you can't access that fingerprint image, just you get the information whether you authenticated or not

There are third party fingerprint SDKs available which provides their SDK & hardware such as [Crossmatch](http://www.crossmatch.com/uareu-sdk-for-android/), [Nitgen](http://www.nitgen.com/eng/product/Hamster3.html#a2), [Tactive](http://precisebiometrics.com/smart-card-reader/android/)

Hope it will help you